# Chevy 4.3 V6 Flywheel Which one?

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission

I am looking at the flywheels for Chevy v6 4.3 and see one is Goodwrench version {?} and one is NON Goodwretch version. I have a 1991 one-piece rear main seal. WHICh one do I need? The engine is going into a Jeep with a T-90 trans but I have the adapters and shaft for the mechanic who's to install.
The adapter calls for 11-inch Clutch and pressure plate which I have.
WHICH flywheel is CORRECT? THANKS!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which one matches the T-90 trans?

Comment: Umm, as far as I know, that is not a link-up issue. The adapter is just to make V6 fit and has a shaft to act as a go-between. The Clutch & pressure plate, and I guess, the flywheel is ALL on Chevy's side of the conversation. What do I need to CHECK the number of BOLTS on this one to tell anything?